# Using additional email inboxes for Sharepoint Workflow approvals

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, workflow, workflow-foundation, exchange-server

One of our managers is encountering an issue with Sharepoint Workflows.
His team has a standard AD user account setup with an email inbox that they all have access to via Outlooks "Open these additional Mailboxes" option.
The Sharepoint workflow is setup to send approvals to this general-use user account.
The problem is, when they receive the emails, it states "You do not have the required permissions to view this task", even though each one of them as well as the general user account has access to the task list in Sharepoint.

Could the fact that Sharepoint is sending approvals to this general email account be causing the issue?  If so, how can this be rectified?  If not, what could be causing this issue?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out the 'general' user account had approve permissions on the List itself, but Limited Access on the Site.  I changed Site permissions for this account to "Approver" and all was well.  Not sure why the Site needed approver status when the List had it specifically, but I guess that's Sharepoint for ya.

Comment: Huh. I'll have to keep that sol'n in my pocket. Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

Are your "Read Access" and/or "Edit Access" "Item-level Permissions" set to "Only their own" on the list? (List->Settings->Advanced Settings). If so, I'd bet that's the culprit.

Comment: Hmm no that's not it.  I noticed "Edit access" was set to only their own, but it still says he doesn't have permissions to view the task. "Read Access" was always set to "All Items"...